# Enabling CORS in CakePHP app

Tags: php, cakephp, cors

I am trying to enable CORS for an API built in CakePHP so that all requests are accessible with the following in the AppController:

```
public function beforeFilter()
{
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
}
```

Is this in the wrong place? As requests are still being blocked.

**Update: It seems this does in fact work BUT because I am doing something like:**

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode(array('message'=>'Hello world!'));
```

**In some of my methods it's acting as though it's overriding the header set the AppController so it's not appearing in the response for the JSON calls.
Any ideas?**

**Update 2: Returning JSON like below, fixes the problem:**

```
$this->response->type('json');
$this->response->body(json_encode(array('message'=>'Hello world!')));
```

**So apparently using `header()` in Cake breaks previous headers?**

Answer (score 15):

You can do this using the cake response object;

```
$this->response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
```

More info on the response object;
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#setting-headers

However, the beforeRender() callback seems a more logical location.

Another option is to add this header in your apache vhost or htaccess examples can be found in the htaccess file of Html5Boilerplate which is a very interesting thing to look at (well documented), because it contains a lot of optimisations that work nicely with cakephp as well;

https://github.com/h5bp/server-configs-apache/blob/master/dist/.htaccess

http://html5boilerplate.com/

Comment: Tried that but I still get the error. Seems as though the header isn't overriding it...

Comment: If you trace the request/response headers in firebug, does the response contain the access-control header? Because if it does, the problem may not be related to this header

Comment: And the response headers? Those should contain the access-control header

Comment: I don't get any, because the response is null due to the access being blocked.

Comment: The same panel should contain the 'request' headers and the 'response' headers. I'm not at my computer now, but here's a screenshot https://www.webkit.org/blog/1091/more-web-inspector-updates/

Comment: Yeah know what you mean, but because the response is refused due to the Access Control Origin I don't get any response from the server.

Comment: Hm, I wonder if that is caused by this header. You can check if the header is output properly by just opening a page of your CakePhp application any page that uses the app controller should send the accesscontrol header

Comment: I have the same problem as OP - Cake doesn't set any of the headers. It's like the headers are overridden later or already sent, I'm not sure.

Comment: **Connection** keep-alive
**Content-Encoding** gzip
**Content-Type** text/html; charset=UTF-8
**Date**  Wed, 27 Jul 2016 18:45:49 GMT
**Server** nginx/1.10.1
**Transfer-Encoding** chunked

This the header information present in response header.

Answer (score -3):

Based on what I found out here: [Sending correct JSON content type for CakePHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14945861/sending-correct-json-content-type-for-cakephp)

The correct way to return JSON in CakePHP is like so:

```
$this->response->type('json');
$this->response->body(json_encode(array('message'=>'Hello world!')));
```

This is because the headers can be overridden and therefore the CORS doesn't work unless you do it the 'proper' way using the response object in Cake.